# Merging records from two '.CSV' files in python

Tags: python, csv

I have two '.csv' files in the below format:
First File :

```
Roll_num Class_Name
1         ABC
2         DEF
5         PQR
27        UVW
```

Second File :

```
Roll_num Marks Grade
1        75    A
2        60    C
27       68    B
61       45    E
```

Now i want to add a column in the second file appending a column 'Class_Name' from First File. The data in both the files has duplicates in it and is not sorted.

I have written the following code that writes our required data from 2 files into a new file.

```
import csv

path="xyz"
file_read=open(path + "ClassName.CSV", "r")
reader_ClassName = csv.reader(file_read)

read_all_data=open(path + "Student.CSV", "r")
reader_Student =csv.reader(read_all_data)
write_all_data=open( path +"Student_Classname.CSV", "w")

for line_Student in reader_Student:
        Roll_Student=line_Student[0]
        for line_ClassName in reader_ClassName:
            Roll_ClassName=line_ClassName[0]
            ClassName=line_ClassName[1]         
            if(Roll_ClassName == Roll_Student):
                string= Roll_Student +","+ClassName  +"\n"
                print string
                write_all_data.write(string)
                break
```

Output Expected :

```
Roll_num Marks Grade Class_Name
1        75    A     ABC
2        60    C     DEF
27       68    B     UVW
61       45    E     LMN
```

Output our code generates:

```
   Roll_num Marks Grade Class_Name
    1        75    A     ABC
    2        60    C     DEF
```

There is some issue in reading the Third line from Second inner 'for' loop. 
We have hundreds of thousands of records in both the files.

Comment: Is there missing data? There is no value "LMN" in the input, but it appears in the output.

Comment: Are values in `Roll_num` unique in each file?

Comment: Try it with less data.

Comment: There is more data in both the files.So I have just given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to avoid `loop in loop` by reading the whole ClassName.csv file and put into an dictionary first. I suggest the idea below

```
mydict = {}
for each_line in ClassName_csvfile:
     rollnum = get_roll_num()
     classname = get_class_name()
     mydict[rollnum]=classname 

for each_line in Student_csv_file:
     rollnum = get_roll_num()
     mark = get_mark()
     grade = get_grade()
     Classname = ''
     if mydict.has_key(rollnum):
        Classname = mydict[rollnum]
     writetofile(rollnum, mark, grade, Classname)
```

Update: you can use `if rollnum in mydict:` instead of `mydict.has_key(rollnum)` if you are using `Python 2.3+`. I am using python 2.7 and both works

P/s: Sorry for not commenting as it requires me 50 reputations

Answer (score 0):

I have named first CSV file as `hash.csv` and second CSV file as `data.csv`. Below script will help you.

```
import re

# Building up a hash with roll_num and class_name from hash.csv
chash = dict([ re.split('\s+', x.strip()) for x in open('hash.csv').readlines()][1:])

# Building a list of students record from data.csv
data = [ re.split('\s+', x.strip()) for x in open('data.csv').readlines() ][1:]

# Iterating through each data
for x in data:
    if x[0] in chash:
        x.append(chash[x[0]])
        print('{0:<5} {1:<5} {2:<5} {3:<5}'.format(*x))
    else:
        print('{0:<5} {1:<5} {2:<5}'.format(*x))
```

Output:

```
1     75    A  ABC
2     60    C  DEF
27    68    B  UVW
61    45    E
```